# Is “J’ai épluché une orange, mais elle n’est pas complètement épluchée” acceptable?

Tags: temps-grammatical, synonymes

I’m just wondering if these are acceptable or not.
In English, these two are distinguished.

> I peeled an apple, but it isn’t completely peeled.
>
> I was peeling an apple, but it isn’t completely peeled.

In French, are the following acceptable or not? Do these sentences sound weird,                  a little weird or acceptable?

> J’ai épluché une orange, mais elle n’est pas 
>   complètement épluchée.
>
> J'épluchais une orange, mais elle n’est pas 
>   complètement épluchée.
>
> J’ai pelé une orange, mais elle n’est pas 
>   complètement pelée.
>
> Je pelais une orange, mais elle n’est pas 
>   complètement pelée.

If these are acceptable, could I remove the word “complètement”? and would these still be acceptable?
I am not a native French speaker, so I don't have an intuition for judging acceptability.

This is concerning telic verbs. These examples are weird, I know.

Comment: I did my best to turn this into something that can be understood. I hope it matches what you were asking about.

Answer (score 3):

Your propositions are all weird but not for the same reasons. First of all, we (French) would rather say something like "I peeled an apple, but not completely/entirely" (we do not like to reuse the same verb/adjective in a sentence).

Second, the tenses mean different things: if you say "J'ai épluché/pelé...", it means that you were peeling that damn fruit but, somehow, it ended up not completely peeled. However, if you use "J'épluchais/pelais..." then it suggests that you had planned not to peel it completely and it sort of contradicts the use of "mais", because there should be no opposition between the 2 parts of the sentence. So those sentences feel weirder.